# graphs of position vs time, velocity vs time, and acceleration vs time

Tags: graph, vpython, glowscript

I want to produce graphs of position vs time, velocity vs time, and acceleration vs time using Vpython in GlowScript IDE. I am modeling a path, so I will have many different segments of the line (ex. starting from rest to constant speed, constant speed for 30 s, constant speed to rest). Here is what I have so far, but I am not sure where to go from here. How do I finish this? I also need to keep the animation at the top of the ball with the arrow. I can give delta t and acceleration values if needed, but otherwise, the code needs to be able to predict the other values (I cannot input data points and Glowscript does not allow libraries to be imported such as numpy).

````
[What velocity graph should look like][2]
[What acceleration graph should look like][3]
[Code][4]

  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/RWn4C.png
  [2]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/VZKbi.png
  [3]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/ieCta.png
  [4]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/grYHQ```
````

Comment: You didn't actually show the code you have so far.